# Regex find all groups

Tags: regex

I have the following sentence that I want to parse:

**If the quick brown dog jumps over the lazy red dog, then the crazy red dog will run past the lazy red dog.**

I want to find all occurrences of characters inbetween "the" and "red dog".
Current Regex:

```
.*the(.*?)red dog.*
```

Expected Result Groups (note the spaces):
" lazy "
" crazy "
" lazy "

[Current Regex Groups Result using regex101 PHP](http://regex101.com/r/rS2zT1)

How would I modify my current regex to get all of my expected groups?

Comment: Using what language/tool for regex?

Comment: I am using regex101, PHP, same as the link in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
\bthe\b((?:(?!\bthe\b).)*?)\bred dog\b
```

The word boundaries prevent you from matching something like "then" instead of "the", the `(.*?)` has been replaced with `((?:(?!\bthe\b).)*?)` to make sure there isn't a "the" closer to the "red dog" where we can start the match.

Example: http://regex101.com/r/jU6cO9

Comment: first match `quick brown dog jumps over the lazy`. [demo](http://regex101.com/r/qW9lH0)

Comment: Thanks, this was the most reusable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try following regex

```
the(\s+\S+\s+)red dog
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/dV7iK1)

Comment: I would like to include any spaces or special characters that occur in between

Comment: @newuser Updated answer as per this requirement. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Consider the following Regex...

```
   (?<=the)\s?\w*?\s?(?=red dog)
```

Comment: The first match is not what I would like: quick brown dog jumps over the lazy